# show that if $f:[c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ is continuous and $g:[a,b] \rightarrow [c,d]$ is Riemann integrable, then $f\circ g$ is also integrable

Tags: real-analysis

Please, give-me a hint to solve this problem:

> Show that if $f:[c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ is continuous and $g:[a,b] \rightarrow [c,d]$ is Riemann integrable, then $f\circ g$ is also integrable.

If $f\circ g$ were continuous, it would be integrable, but $g$ is said to be only integrable, then it is not possible to conclude that $f\circ g$ is continuous. So, there must be another way.

Comment: it might have something to do with $f$ being uniformly continuous, look at definition of Riemann integral, partitions, upper and lower sums

Comment: Do you know that a (bounded) function (on a bounded interval) is Riemann-integrable iff the set of discontinuities is a null-set?

Comment: Hello, PhoemueX! Since $g$ is integrable, then it is discontinuous in a null-set. I must prove that $fog$ is also discontinuous in a null-set. How to do it?