# Integrability of $f \circ g$ when $f$ is Riemann integrable and $g$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

First I want to refer to 
[show that if $f:[c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ is continuous and $g:[a,b] \rightarrow [c,d]$ is Riemann integrable, then $f\circ g$ is also integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041330/show-that-if-fc-d-rightarrow-mathbb-r-is-continuous-and-ga-b-right).

My case is slightly different with above link.
Question:
If $f:[c,d]\to\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable and $g:[a,b]\to[c,d]$ is continuous, then is $f\circ g$ also integrable?

I guess that it's not true but I failed to find a counterexample. 
Please help me.

Comment: [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/20063), with [an elaboration on site](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1834357).

Comment: @fischer Thank you very much!